# find elements for a specific index value in a multi_index_container indexed by a composite_key

Tags: c++, boost-multi-index

I have to work with the following container, and I would like to know if there is a way to find all Nodes sharing a specific `peerId`.

I think I would be able to figure it out if the second container index was a simple `ordered_non_unique` index, but I'm very  confused by the `multi_index::tag` and  `multi_index::composite_key`. I don't care for the `TimePoint`, I just want to a simple search for all `Node`s with a specified `peerid`

```
using TimePoint = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock>;

typedef int64_t NodeId;
using PeerId = uint32_t;

struct Node {
    NodeId nodeid;  
    PeerId peerid;
    TimePoint nextRequestTime;

    Node(NodeId nodeid_, PeerId peerid_)
        : nodeid(nodeid_), peerid(peerid_),
          nextRequestTime(std::chrono::steady_clock::now()) {}
};

using NodeSet = boost::multi_index_container<
    Node,
    boost::multi_index::indexed_by<
        // index by nodeid
        boost::multi_index::hashed_unique<
            boost::multi_index::member<Node, NodeId, &Node::nodeid>>,
        // sorted by peerid/nextRequestTime
        boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique<
            boost::multi_index::tag<next_request_time>,
            boost::multi_index::composite_key<
                Node,
                boost::multi_index::member<Node, PeerId, &Node::peerid>,
                boost::multi_index::member<Node, TimePoint,
                                           &Node::nextRequestTime>>>>>;

NodeSet nodes;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
nodes.get<next_request_time>().equal_range(my_peerid)
```

which returns a pair of iterators to the beginning and end of the looked-for range.